# How to add Google map_view inside flutter widget?

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I have tried Google flutter map_view library however currently it's not supporting Google map inside flutter widget I want to add Google map inside flutter widget and show annotations on it as well as I want to show custom view on click of annotation. 
Have you know any alternative option for this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can use [mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox/flutter-mapbox-gl) is the one with examples you can find how to use it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oc1mktx0Zn8).

Hope it helps